# Facing issues with link_to "Edit" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display all the metrics in a table format with an edit option. But, I end up with the below error

[image]

In Index view, I am able to see all the data. But when I click on edit link, it is not redirecting to edit view where I have different columns to be showed.

**index view:**

```
<%= form_for :metrics_controller, url: metrics_path(@metric), method: :get do |f| %>
  <table id="metrics">
    <thead>
    <tr id="AllMetricColumnNames">
      <th id="CommentsColumn">Comments</th>
      <th id="EditColumn">Edit</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <% @metricAll.each do |data| %>
      <tr id="AllMetricValues">
        <td id="Comments"><%= data.Comments %></td>
        <td id="EditButton"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_metric_path(@metricAll) %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @metricAll = Metric.all
  end

  def show
    @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
  end

  private def post_params
    params.require(:metric).permit(:Metric, :Comments)
  end
end
```

**routes:**

```
  root 'metrics#index'
  get 'index' => 'metrics#index'
  get 'edit' => 'metrics#edit'
  resources :metrics
```

Comment: Why did you add `get` routes ? I think `resources :metrics` would be enough if you want to use default rails routes pattern

Answer (score 1):

You're passing ALL the metrics for the edit route. Move from

```
<td id="EditButton"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_metric_path(@metricAll) %></td>
```

to

```
<td id="EditButton"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_metric_path(data) %></td>
```

`data` is the current metric in your code

Comment: Now, I am getting this error: 
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Metrics#index
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"metrics", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Your data variable is nil - try replacing it with the ID of the object that you want to edit

Comment: Remove `get` routes and then try.

Comment: Yes, remove this line `get 'edit' => 'metrics#edit'`. That's already defined in `resources :metrics` better

Comment: Removed get routes. Now in the index view, when i click on edit link, I am getting this error.

ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey in MetricsController#edit

Unknown primary key for table AutomatedThresholding in model Metric.

Comment: Update your question with suggested answer. remove both get routes and replace `@metricAll` with `data` and then hover over that edit link and check what url is forming

Comment: As suggested removed get routes and replaced @metricAll with data.Metric.  

Now, on hovering to edit link, I see it as http://localhost/metrics/Metric1/edit

Comment: Wait, why data.Metric? It should be just data

Comment: When I have just data, I am getting this error: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Metrics#index No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"metrics", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: try with data.id but it's really strange. it seems any of your metric objects is nil to me. try to print them.

Comment: another try could be `edit_metric_path(id: data.id)`

Comment: Ohh.. I don't have the column id in my data object. Is that required in my table or do I need to modify my method edit as I don't have id column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183567/discussion-between-mallela-sriprakash-and-ursus).

Comment: I definitely think that's the problem. If you have a different primary key than id, try this  `self.primary_key = '<your_column>'`

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshot, the error is within the model. 
Also, as mentioned by others, you should remove those `get` routes as the `resources :metrics` will generate the necessary routes for all your CRUD actions a.ka. for the `index, show, edit, new, create, update, destroy`.

My guess is that the `metric.rb` file has a `belongs_to :automated_thresholding` relationship but the `metrics` database table is missing the field `automated_thresholding_id`.

You should create a migration to add that field

`add_reference :metrics, :automated_thresholding`

Comment: This is what I have in my model: 
class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'AutomatedThresholding'
end

Comment: I guess you must have a database table named `automated_thresholdings`. If that's the case, this syntax `self.table_name = AutomatedThresholding`  is wrong. This should be correct `self.table_name = 'automated_thresholdings'`

Read more: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name